# how to host a normal python project on internet which uses urllib

Tags: python

I have written a normal python program using urllib. I want to host it on webpage. Is it possible.If then how?My program is this:

```
import urllib
import re


share = raw_input("enter the share name")
urlinput=share.upper()
u=str(urlinput)
print(urlinput)
regex='<span id="yfs_l84_'+share+'">(.+?)</span>'
pattern=re.compile(regex)

htmlfile=urllib.urlopen("http://in.finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+urlinput)
text=htmlfile.read()
text=str(text)
result=re.findall(pattern,text)
print(result)
```

Comment: yes it is possible, you can do this easily with any of the python microframeworks

Comment: also, i believe yahoo has a finance api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a web framework, such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) or [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/).

I recommend Flask, which is very easy to use, and its documentation is very well written, even for beginners

Comment: can i run it on any web hosting server?

Comment: As long as it supports mod_wsgi, or other python modules for the web server, yes. Just make sure it does support Python.

Comment: This means it i can run on google app engine and appfog using django or flask.Right?

Comment: If you are using Google App Engine, I am pretty sure, you'll have to use their own framework with their own API

Comment: You can, but not with the framework I just talked about. You'll have to play with Google App Engine API.

Comment: I think it's because you have no idea of what you're talking about. This kind of question requires some knowledge that you obviously don't have right now. But I don't see why you shouldn't be asking this. Good luck to make this happen. PS: Don't forget to accept the answer if you think I actually answered your question

Comment: I am sorry i cannot vote up your answer bcoz i dont have 15 reputation